# Can not retrieve value from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I get the data from server every `10 seconds` as

```
var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/monitoring/rest/graph/temperature').then(function(r){
            data.response = r.data;
            console.log(r.data);
            extractTemperatureReadings(r.data)
            data.calls++;
            $timeout(poller, 10000)
        });
    }
    poller();
```

and then I want to extract certain values which I do as

```
function extractTemperatureReadings(apiResponse) {
    var readings = {}
    readings['reading'] = apiResponse.map(function(value){value.reading})
    readings['dateTime'] = apiResponse.map(function(value){value.dateTime})

    console.log('Temperature reading: ' + JSON.stringify(readings))
    return readings
}
```

However on Browser `console.log`, I see

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
monitoring.js:64 Temperature reading: {"reading":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"dateTime":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}
```

where each Object when I click, I get

```
0: Object
dateTime: "2015-08-31 19:56:28.335000"
moduleId: "110010 "
reading: "400"
__proto__: Object
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never `return` from your `.map` calls

```
readings['reading'] = apiResponse.map(function(value){ return value.reading })
readings['dateTime'] = apiResponse.map(function(value){ return value.dateTime })
```

Also, you don't have to stringify your object to see it in the console with preceding text, simply do:

```
console.log('Temperature reading: ', readings)
```

Comment: I am still in my `Scala` senses :(. Thanks @tymeJV